# Why doesn't Alice ever use the rifle we see her holding in the movie poster?

Tags: props, posters, resident-evil

In the US theatrical poster for *Resident Evil*, Alice is seen holding a rifle in her right hand.

[image]

There is also a promotional photo of Alice holding the rifle:

[image]

But in the movie itself, she never actually uses it, only the pistol in her left hand. Why is that?

Comment: Presumably because the image is a promotional one and it makes her look more badass than just a pistol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The weapon, according to the [Internet Movie Firearms Database](http://imfdb.org) is a Heckler & Koch G36K with a Heckler & Koch AG36 Grenade Launcher attached. There is only one in the movie and it is carried and used by One ([Colin Salmon](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Colin_Salmon)).
In the entry within the Database for that movie and that weapon, it is stated:

> Alice ([Milla Jovovich](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Milla_Jovovich)) is seen holding the G36K by the AG36 grenade launcher's pistol grip in the US theatrical poster.

It isn't explained why they show Alice holding that particular weapon in the theatrical poster when that character never uses it in the movie, but I would have to agree with user [Paulie_D](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/34317/paulie-d) in [his comment](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/116408/why-doesnt-alice-ever-use-the-rifle-we-see-her-holding-in-the-movie-poster#comment200995_116408):

> Presumably because the image is a promotional one and it makes her look more badass than (with) just a pistol.

Comment: i was also wondering when i bought the DVD of the movie and i saw her holding that but in the whole film she never used it but the axe and the pistol, She fights zombies by Kicking them and snapping the head. In my opinion, Is this the main Reason why is everyone so mad at this FIlm? because Milla isn't using that Rifle? Well that's Complicated

Comment: Well, I'm not so sure I would agree with "everyone is so mad at this fil" is really true any more (although there were many varied complaints when it originally came out). After all, there is Resident Evil (2002), Resident Evil: Apocalypse (2004), Resident Evil: Extinction (2007), Resident Evil: Afterlife (2010), Resident Evil: Retribution (2012) and Resident Evil: The Final Chapter (2016), plus Resident Evil: Welcome to Raccoon City (2021). Also, as of 2021, Resident Evil is 21st highest grossing movie based on a video game, The Final Chapter is #6, Afterlife #9, Retribution #13, Extinction

Comment: #18, and Apocalypse is #19. At this point, people can be "angry" all they want, but Milla Jovovich and Paul W. S. Anderson could care less all the way to the bank. Collectively the franchise is said to have made about 1.2 billion-with-a-B and Jovovich is supposedly worth about 50 million.